# Trouble understanding a typedef along function pointers

Tags: c, pointers, winapi, syntax, typedef

Even after reading some answers here on SO regarding this topic, I'm having a bad time trying to understand what exactly the following syntax does:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *DllEntryProc)(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved);
```

**My guess:** 
It defines the `DllEntryProc` data type as an alias for `BOOL`, where `DllEntryProc` is a pointer to a function that takes one `HINSTANCE`, one `DWORD` and one `LPVOID` as arguments and returns a `WINAPI`?

The code above is part of [this article](https://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/) regarding how to load a DLL from memory. The function is then called like this:

```
DllEntryProc entry = (DllEntryProc) someValue;
(*entry)((HINSTANCE)baseAddress, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0);
```

Returning a `BOOL` (thanks to that typedef), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It defines the `DllEntryProc` data type <strike>as an alias for BOOL</strike>, where DllEntryProc is a pointer to a function that takes one HINSTANCE, one DWORD and one LPVOID as arguments and returns a <strike>WINAPI</strike> `BOOL`

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *DllEntryProc)(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved);
```

`DllEntryProc` is a new type like `int` and you can declare variables of this type just like you can declare variables of type `int`.

```
DllEntryProc somevar;
```

Now the value that you can assign to `somevar` should be of type `DllEntryProc` which is a pointer to a function of the said type.

Comment: What is the significance of `WINAPI`?

Comment: `WINAPI` is one of the calling conventions. Read about calling conventions.

Comment: @NikhilCSB `WINAPI` is a preprocessor macro that resolves to the `__stdcall` calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

- When a typedef is used for function pointer, you give it a **friendly name** which makes it easier to create and reference pointers using that definition. Example

  ```
  #include<stdio.h>
  int test(int a, char b, float c){
          printf("a=%d,b=%c,c=%f\n",a,b,c);
  }
  typedef int (*test_p)(int a, char b, float c);

  int main(){
          test_p ptr = test;
          ptr(10, 'a', 5.5);
  }

  # gcc test.c 
  # ./a.out 
  a=10,b=a,c=5.500000
  ```
- Back to your function pointer declaration.

  ```
  typedef BOOL (WINAPI *DllEntryProc)(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved);
  ```

  is same as:

  ```
  typedef int (*test_p)(int a, char b, float c);
  ```

  Here **WINAPI** is a macro that evaluates to __stdcall, a Microsoft-specific keyword that specifies a calling convention where the callee cleans the stack. The function's caller and callee need to agree on a calling convention to avoid corrupting the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The `typedef` creates a function pointer type. Briefly, function pointers work like this:

Given a function `void func (void)`, a function pointer to such a function is declared `void (*ptr) (void)`. A `typedef` of that same function pointer can be either written as:

- `typedef void (*ptr_t) (void);`, usage `ptr_t ptr;`, or
- `typedef void ptr_t (void);`, usage `ptr_t* ptr`.

The former style is perhaps the most common and what the Windows API uses. Personally I find the latter style clearer since it is consistent with object pointers, but it is just a matter of preference - either is fine.

The function pointer can now be used to call the function either with `ptr()` or `(*ptr)()` - these are equivalent, again just different styles.

---

Dissecting `typedef BOOL (WINAPI *DllEntryProc)(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved);` in detail:

- `BOOL` is the Windows API style boolean type. The Windows API predates C99, so they use a custom boolean type.
- `WINAPI` is a macro which hides the non-standard syntax specifying the [*calling convention*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=vs-2019) used by the function. It expands to `__stdcall`. Briefly, calling convention is about whether the caller or the callee is responsible for stacking parameters.

  Using the right calling convention is very important when communicating with DLL:s, because DLL:s are language agnostic and various programming languages use different calling conventions. C and C++ tend to use `__cdecl` calling convention by default (see the link), so a different one needs to be specified in cases where it matters, such as DLL:s.
- `DllEntryProc` is the new name for the function pointer type.
- `HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved` are function parameters. It is optional (but good practice) to use parameter names during a typedef.

---

As for what this type does, it creates a function pointer to the DllMain/DllEntryPoint function (different names same meaning) present in the DLL. Each DLL has such a function which is a "constructor" of sorts, called when you load the DLL. When coding your own DLL:s from scratch, you have to provide this function (but there's a lot of rules about what you shouldn't do from inside DllMain).

Generally, it is common practice in the application using a DLL, to have a function pointer for each DLL function, since the `GetProcAddress` which you use to get functions from a DLL just returns a generic function pointer.

`(*entry)((HINSTANCE)baseAddress, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0);` is an explicit function call to the DllMain/DllEntryPoint. Since it is a function pointer, the alternative but equivalent syntax is:

`entry((HINSTANCE)baseAddress, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0);`

This is perhaps clearer style, since it looks just as a function call.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation! I'll remeber to upvote it once I'm allowed to ;)